# Edit Input name value

Tags: angularjs

I'm adding form elements dynamically using AngularJS as you can see below and it works very fine.

But sometimes, the user need to change the value of the placeholder and replace it with a value with his choice and I don't see if it's possible or not ?

Here is my HTML

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
   <div class="col-xs-3">
       <div class="input-group">
           <span class="input-group-addon">Tr.</span>
           <input id="tr-dpa" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter mobile number">

           <button class="remove"  ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
       </div>
   </div>
   </fieldset>

   <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
         <button type="submit" class="add" ng-click="addNewChoice()">
         +
         </button>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my script,

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
  };



  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
  };

});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/1258/)

Comment: do you want change the placeholder name dynamically?

Comment: Try like this `placeholder="{{your placeholder}}"`

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes i want that the user can change the placeholder or the name of the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your `choices` array like this:

```
$scope.choices = [{
    id: 'choice1',
    placeholder: 'Enter Mobile Number'
  }];
```

And, inside `ng-repeat`,

```
<input id="tr-dpa" class="form-control" placeholder="{{choice.placeholder}}">
```

Now, when you add new input, ask for a placeholder and push it along with id.

```
$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
    $scope.choices.push({
      'id': 'choice' + newItemNo,
      placeholder: $scope.placeholder
    });
    $scope.placeholder = "sample placeholder"
  };
```

And, `$scope.placeholder` would be in HTML,

```
 <input type="text" value="sample placeholder" ng-model="placeholder">
 <button type="submit" class="add" ng-click="addNewChoice()">
   +
 </button>
```

[**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/1261/)

Comment: Oh thank you ! 
That work fine, i'll accept your answer

Comment: @NabilCHOUKRI glad I could help! :)